# Page overlay only on first time load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my home page, I have an overlay with a button to enter the website. On click, the overlay disappears. The overlay should only appear once, on first page load. Here is my issue:

1. When I first enter the home page, the overlay appears (as it should be)
2. When I then click on the logo or the home menu item in the navigation, the home page reloads (as normal), BUT the overlay is being displayed again (for the second time).
3. When I click again on the logo or the home menu item (now for the third time), the overlay is nog being displayed anymore (as it should be).

My question: why is the overlayd being displayed the second time I enter the page?

Here is my code:

```
var session = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
    console.log(session);
    if (session !== null) {
        $('.overlay').hide();
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem('session', 1);
```

Comment: Just so I understand, are you wanting to show the overlay every time a new session is active, or should it only appear once when the user lands on the page and then never again? If the latter, sessionStorage won't accomplish this. When the browser window is closed, the session ends and then when they re-visit, the overlay will appear again. Try using localStorage for this instead or set a cookie.

Comment: you need to show the code where you are loading overlay

Comment: The overlay must be showed every time a new session is active.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. it's set overlay show only once in 24 hours when you visit the website first time.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
               if ($.cookie('overlay_status') != '1') {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.overlay').show();
                    $.cookie('overlay_status', '1', { expires: 1}); 
                    }, 20000); 
                } else {
                 $('.overlay').hide();
}
    });
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I suppose I need to download a plugin to use this code?

Answer (score 0):

This eventually seems to do the trick for me...

```
function setCookie(key, value, expiry) {
    var expires = new Date();
    expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (expiry * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
}

function getCookie(key) {
    var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
}

function eraseCookie(key) {
    var keyValue = getCookie(key);
    setCookie(key, keyValue, '-1');
}

if (getCookie('overlay_status') != '1') {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.overlay').show();
        setCookie('overlay_status', '1', '1');
    }, 20000);
} else {
    $('.overlay').hide();
}
```